# Entity framework add record without checking if it exist or already added

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, large-data

I have a large CSV file from which I need to add items to Database (more than a Million rows). I have chunkified the original csv to limit row entry to 1000 rows at a time. I have experimented with few  logics of adding to Db

```
var modelObjects = new List<ModelObject>();
... add 1000 rows to modelObjects
context.ModelObjects.AddRange(ModelObjects);
context.SaveChanges();
... repeat until all data is added to db
```

Any approach that I am aware of makes EF track Id and look for duplicates and slow down the additon process. I want a way where I can simply Add the Range without checking for duplicates. If conflict on AddingRange simply replace that item.

Something like

`context.ModelObjects.AddRange(ModelObjects) --force --ignoreduplicatecheck`

Comment: My advice: if you're adding that many records - don't use Entity Framework. For all bulk operations, there are better tools. Leave EF for CRUD operations.

Comment: EF is great tool but it is not a silver bullet. I would forgo the use of EF in this case and use something like Sql Bulk Insert, ADO.NET with a Table Value Parameter, or SqlCmd.exe directly.

Comment: I don't think that EF is the best tools for adding 1mln rows. You should use ADO.NET or even better if you use direct bulk t-sql script or  third party utils.

Comment: I would suggest using SQL bulk insert.  Do you have access to modify the database schema?  You could have EF just call a stored procedure that inserts the data.

Comment: Time to sql bluck insert or insert. insert it all into a temp table then use a SQL merge to handle the duplicate etc.

Comment: Not sure for it but doesn't  `.AsNoTracking()` should do it? [EF Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, bulk adding rows is very slow when the rows contain ids, because entity framework has no option but to check whether each id already exists.

If you want the bulk addition of the rows to go as fast as possible with entity framework, (which may still be slower than your requirements, but this is yet to be seen,) then you have to make sure that your id column is auto-generated by entity framework, and refrain from specifying the value of the id in each bulk-inserted row. This way, entity framework will generate unique ids by itself, so depending on the database that you are using, it may be able to bulk-insert your rows without having to check whether each id already exists.

If your bulk-inserted rows already have some ids that you want to do something meaningful with, you may want to store these ids in a separate column (say, `id2`,) which is not indexed, so it does not slow down your bulk insert, and perform an extra query after the bulk insert completes, to find duplicates, merge them with existing rows, etc.